# Barcode Scanner wrong output

Tags: ubuntu, barcode-scanner

LS300 from Reichelt is working perfectly for Text under Ubuntu 12.04.1. But when I am scanning a special character it messes up. My Codes are CODE_128 barcodes and i got the following output:

- 20-1833026 --> 20'1833026 = fail
- 00:23:A6:35:F1:44 --> 00é23éA6é35éF1é44 = fail
- 7613223003586 --> 7613223003586 = ok

I already checked ASCII Tables, but the é is not even in the normal ASCII set. Could that be because i have a german keyboard layout? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: btw, same on a windows computer. But when I'm scanning the barcodes with the android app "Barcode Scanner", the output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the wrong interal language setting. even tough the scanner was set to "english" default, it did read ":" as "é" and "-" as "/". setting it to german solved the problem.